# How to upload file using selenium webdriver and python in the div or button tags

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

Faced a problem, I can not upload the file into tags div and button. I use selenium webdriver and Python 3.6.3. Actually here is the code of the block where you need to insert the file:

```html
<div value="[object Object]" class="btn-bar"><button class="progress"><div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="progress-bar" style="width: 0%;"><span style="color: black;">SELECT NEW FILE</span></div></button> <div class="btn">Upload</div></div>
```

and the Python code itself:

```html
    def Work_with_IPFS(self):
        self.address_file = ['/root/PycharmProjects/test/test_file/config.js',
                             '/root/PycharmProjects/test/test_file/nB+DIdSC',
                             '/root/PycharmProjects/test/test_file/photo_2017-12-04_15-01-28.jpg',
                             '/root/PycharmProjects/test/test_file/prod.env.js']
        try:
            _ipfs_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a')
            _ipfs_btn.click()
        except Exception as e:
            print('ERROR in IPFS: ', format(e))
        _ipfs_upload = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/button')
        for i in self.address_file:
            _ipfs_upload.send_keys(i)
            print('file is {}'.format(i))
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div').click()
            time.sleep(40)
            check_ipfs = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li/label/span[2]')
            print(check_ipfs)
```

I tried everything, but nothing works.

Comment: Why do you want to upload file to div or button? What is the point? Also you should provide HTML and Python code as simple text, but not as link to image

Comment: The fact is that our developers have implemented the process of uploading files to the system. How to either influence this is impossible. On the Internet, there are many examples of how to write files in input, but there is no way in div or button. Code spread below.

Comment: Div or button cannot be used for file upload - AFAIK it should always be `<input type="file">` node...  Did you try `seld.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="file"]').send_keys("/path/to/file")`?

Comment: Tried, but the page is completely generated React JS and //input[@type="file"]  does not find. If there was "input" then the problem would quickly be resolved, and so I sit and look for opportunities like all the same to implement this task (((